# Rails Time class has a TimeZone Bug. Can this be confirmed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here goes :

```
Time.zone.now => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
Time.zone.now => Wed, 15 Aug 2012 06:05:37 EDT -04:00
Time.zone.now + 39.years => Tue, 15 Aug 2051 06:06:03 EST -05:00
```

And so you have it, the end of our fabled Eastern Daylight Time has been prophesied by Ruby on Rails to end in the year 2051.

Also works for any other TimeZone changing area.

```
Time.zone
 => "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" 
1.9.2p180 :003 > Time.zone.now
 => Wed, 15 Aug 2012 03:08:57 PDT -07:00 
1.9.2p180 :004 > Time.zone.now + 39.years
 => Tue, 15 Aug 2051 03:08:57 PST -08:00
```

This exists in Rails 3.0 and in Rails 3.2.6

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like a bug. It's not Rails, however, it's the Ruby **Time** class. It has problems with times after 2038.

For example, with Ruby 1.8.7:

```
> Time.local(2037,8,16,9,30,15)
 => Sun Aug 16 09:30:15 -0400 2037 
>
> Time.local(2038,8,16,9,30,15)
 => Mon Aug 16 09:30:15 -0500 2038
```

JRuby 1.6.7.2 - for instance - does not have this problem:

```
> Time.local(2038,8,16,9,30,15)
 => Mon Aug 16 09:30:15 -0400 2038
```

Note that, on MRI Ruby on 64-bit systems, the ActiveSupport time extension which supports the addition of durations ultimately calls Time.local or Time.utc via this method in active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:

```
      # Returns a new Time if requested year can be accommodated by Ruby's Time class
      # (i.e., if year is within either 1970..2038 or 1902..2038, depending on system architecture);
      # otherwise returns a DateTime
      def time_with_datetime_fallback(utc_or_local, year, month=1, day=1, hour=0, min=0, sec=0, usec=0)
        ::Time.send(utc_or_local, year, month, day, hour, min, sec, usec)
      rescue
        offset = utc_or_local.to_sym == :local ? ::DateTime.local_offset : 0
        ::DateTime.civil(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, offset)
      end
```

I guess the issue is that for years >= 2038, they were expecting an overflow exception and for DateTime to be used instead. On 64-bit systems, this doesn't happen.

UPDATE: This analysis is incorrect for Ruby 1.9.2+. Time.local works as expected, but the original problem still occurs.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're inferring, but I'm using a 64-bit system on which the bug was discovered.

Comment: Ruby 1.9(.3) doesn't seem to have this problem?!

Comment: Trip: Yes. The calculation should fallback to using Date on a 32-bit system with MRI Ruby.

Comment: Hmmm. With Ruby 1.9.2, Time.local works, but I still see a bug with the original problem.